# c# Textbox: convert Number to Char

Tags: c#

I need some help to convert asci code from int to char using KeyPress event   (e.KeyChar)

the text book says:

- (int) e.keyChar yields ASCII number
- (char)200 converts number into char (can someone help with this step ?)

```
    private void tbxInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
            // input character                           
                int key = e.KeyChar;
                int codeUp;   
            // add 1 to ascicode (do some manipulation)
                codeUp = key + 1;
            // convert ascii code back to char (help!)
                newChr = char(codeUp);
            //display ascii char in textbox
                lblOutput.Text = newChr.ToString();
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: `(char)codeUp` ?

Comment: Just to be clear: `(int)e.KeyChar` actually returns the UTF16 code for the character, which happens to be the same as ASCII for the first 128 Unicode characters. For your example code 200, the Unicode character is `È` but there is no ASCII character with that code; however the Latin 1 ANSI character set (ISO-8859-1) does have the same character `È` with that code.

Comment: Matthew -thx -  i am just following and quoting the textbook - and this is a small exercise. the idea here is to create a "secret code" by typing a letter - example "d" - and then apply a formula (convert to ascii code => apply formula (code + 1) => returning to the "secret code - the new ascii char". the key question is how to code ascii number back to char ?

Comment: It's what TheGeneral said: `newChr = (char) codeUp;`

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion `(char)codeUp` is indeed good but still an error 'the name 'newChr' does not exist in the current context' was produced.
This was solved by adding a declaration to the //input character block `char newChr;`

Now it works.

Thanks.